# latex figure over multiple page

Tags: captions

I'm working on my thesis right now.

In a section I have an image that is too big for one page, so this should be displayed over several pages.
My current code looks like this:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figures/mk_venlo} 
  \caption{Produktions Datenbank}
  \label{fig:dbmkvenlo}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What a big image. Scaling or landscape mode(rotate=90) aren't an option?

Comment: What is in the figure? Can you show the output and what you would like? It's hard to imagine a situation where you'd want latex to split your figure for you...

Comment: i added a picture, i hope it's better understandable now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manually split the image by croping it. In case you need captions for the first subimages, you can use `\ContinuedFloat` from the caption package.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim=0pt 5.6cm 0pt 0pt, clip]{example-image-10x16}
    \caption{text}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \ContinuedFloat
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim=0pt 0pt 0pt 5.6cm, clip]{example-image-10x16}
    \caption{text}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```